# Making rectangle on html canvas click

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make rectangle on canvas on event 'click'. I've made event listener but when I click rectangle seems to be way of area where I clicked. Basically I want rectangle to appear around the clicked area. This is my code:

```
 const cursor_pdf = document.getElementsByClassName('react-pdf__Page__canvas')[0];
 cursor_pdf?.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    const rect = cursor_pdf.getBoundingClientRect();

    const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    const marker = cursor_pdf.getContext("2d");
    marker.beginPath();
    marker.lineWidth = "3";
    marker.strokeStyle = "red";
    marker.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
    marker.stroke();
});
```

After this when I click with cursor on this blue dot ( not really on screen just to point mouse click) Rectangle appears way off click.

[image]

But I want it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/z0rvLw24/. Of course, the only issue is that the top-left corner of the rectangle is where the cursor is clicked, but that is easily fixed by subtracting half the square's width (i.e. `- 25`) on the x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cursor_pdf = document.getElementsByClassName('react-pdf__Page__canvas')[0];
 cursor_pdf?.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    const rect = cursor_pdf.getBoundingClientRect();

    //subtract half of the rectangle width/height so it's centered
    const x = e.clientX - rect.left - 25;
    const y = e.clientY - rect.top - 25;

    const marker = cursor_pdf.getContext("2d");
    marker.beginPath();
    marker.lineWidth = "3";
    marker.strokeStyle = "red";
    marker.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
    marker.stroke();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="react-pdf__Page__canvas"></canvas>
```